# How to calculate the difference between grouped row in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset with the number of views per article.

[image]

I'm trying to calculate the additional number of views per day, for each story, so I can graph it.

I manage to do it for one story only.

```
storyviews = stats[['title', 'views']].sort_values(by=['title','views'])
storyviews = stats[stats["title"] == "Getting Started with TDD"]
storyviews = storyviews[["title","views"]].sort_values(by=['title','views'])
difference = storyviews.set_index('title').diff()
difference = difference.dropna(subset=['views'])
difference
```

and I got the correct result.

[image]

Is there a way to do it in one pass for all the stories?

DATASET

```
y,m,d,mediumID,title,link,publication,mins,views,reads,readRatio,fans,pubDate,liveDate
2020,06,30,a1777d8bf7e,Swift — Filtering: A Real Example,https://levelup.gitconnected.com/swift-filtering-a-real-example-a1777d8bf7e,Level Up Coding,4 min read,35,13,37.142857142857146,1,2020-06-17,2020-06-26
2020,06,30,6f5fc68b0b43,SwiftUI 2: an overview,https://levelup.gitconnected.com/swiftui-2-an-overview-6f5fc68b0b43,Level Up Coding,3 min read,43,22,51.16279069767442,2,2020-06-24,2020-06-24
2020,07,01,a1777d8bf7e,Swift — Filtering: A Real Example,https://levelup.gitconnected.com/swift-filtering-a-real-example-a1777d8bf7e,Level Up Coding,4 min read,37,13,35.13513513513514,1,2020-06-17,2020-06-26
2020,07,01,6f5fc68b0b43,SwiftUI 2: an overview,https://levelup.gitconnected.com/swiftui-2-an-overview-6f5fc68b0b43,Level Up Coding,3 min read,57,29,50.87719298245614,10,2020-06-24,2020-06-24
2020,07,02,a1777d8bf7e,Swift — Filtering: A Real Example,https://levelup.gitconnected.com/swift-filtering-a-real-example-a1777d8bf7e,Level Up Coding,4 min read,37,13,35.13513513513514,1,2020-06-17,2020-06-26
2020,07,02,6f5fc68b0b43,SwiftUI 2: an overview,https://levelup.gitconnected.com/swiftui-2-an-overview-6f5fc68b0b43,Level Up Coding,3 min read,76,43,56.578947368421055,15,2020-06-24,2020-06-24
2020,07,03,a1777d8bf7e,Swift — Filtering: A Real Example,https://levelup.gitconnected.com/swift-filtering-a-real-example-a1777d8bf7e,Level Up Coding,4 min read,40,13,34.21052631578947,1,2020-06-17,2020-06-26
2020,07,03,6f5fc68b0b43,SwiftUI 2: an overview,https://levelup.gitconnected.com/swiftui-2-an-overview-6f5fc68b0b43,Level Up Coding,3 min read,152,70,46.05263157894737,20,2020-06-24,2020-06-24
```

Thanks,
Nicolas

Comment: Please provide your dataframe and not the picture.

Comment: I added the dataset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you give this a shot?

```py
cols = ['title', 'views']
storyviews = stats[cols].sort_values(by=cols)
res = storyviews.set_index('title').groupby('title', sort=False).diff().dropna()
```

Output:

```
                                   views
title                                   
SwiftUI 2: an overview              14.0
SwiftUI 2: an overview              19.0
SwiftUI 2: an overview              76.0
Swift — Filtering: A Real Example     2.0
Swift — Filtering: A Real Example     0.0
Swift — Filtering: A Real Example     3.0
```

For plotting the legend, title ..., the you might want to ask another question. I don't have an answer. To get you started on the plot, try this.

```py
res.reset_index().groupby('title', sort=False).plot()
```

Comment: This is working!!! Thanks a lot.

Any idea how I can plot it?
I try to add the .plot() at the end, but I have only 1 line, and not one per story.

Comment: @nsavoini I don't have an answer. But, see the updated post to get you started.

Answer (score 0):

So you're just trying to get a sum of all views per title? Here's one-way using dictionary conversion from a pandas DataFrame:

#### Edited with updated answer in for loop

```
...
dict = df.groupby('title').groups
for key in dict:
    numpyarray_diff_between = np.diff(np.array(list(dict[key])))
...
```

Comment: Sorry, my question wasn't clear enough. What I have in my dataset is the total number of views per day.
What I'm looking for is the additional number of views per day.
I added a picture of the result to show you.

Comment: Ah, so the difference between each subsequent day. I'll edit my answer above.

Comment: Sorry, It doesn't seem to be working.
This is the result I have:
array([6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7])

array([7])

array([6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7])

array([6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7])

array([6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7])

array([6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7])
array([6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7])